# How to edit qt assistant style sheet?

Tags: qt, web

I can't find `qt assistant` style sheet `(css)` file.
I have installed `Qt Assistant Version 5.5.1` in arch, and i want to edit/customize font, etc.
How i can do this?
or where the `css` files is?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does not use any `qss` in your OS and therefore is used the native style. All the Qt applications which forwards the `argc` and `argv` in the `main()` to the `QApplication` can be started with stylesheet given by argument

```
my_app -stylesheet=my_nice_style.qss
```

This works for my Qt Assistant from the Qt version 4.8.7 in Gentoo.